# Sorting a dictionary where values are also dictionaries?

Tags: python

If the dictionary is like that:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

and I want to sort it by value I use the `sorted` function as follows:

```
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

How could I do the same with the following dictionary, if I want to sort it by "number":

```
d = {
    "a": {"description": "first letter", "number": 1},
    "b": {"description": "second letter", "number": 2},
    "c": {"description": "third letter", "number": 3}
}
```

Comment: Pick the key you want out of `x[1]` in the `key` lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `x[1]["number"]` in your lambda

```
n [40]: d
Out[40]:
{'b': {'description': 'second letter', 'number': 2},
 'a': {'description': 'first letter', 'number': 1},
 'c': {'description': 'third letter', 'number': 3}}

In [41]: sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]["number"])
Out[41]:
[('a', {'description': 'first letter', 'number': 1}),
 ('b', {'description': 'second letter', 'number': 2}),
 ('c', {'description': 'third letter', 'number': 3})]
```

Comment: thanks i was trying to do lambda x:x[1][1] even if it makes no sens, foolish